# Dynamically audio source change not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Dynamically audio source change not working on opera and safari but working fine on firefox, chrome and ie.

```
  <audio id="audio" controls="" >
        <source src="" type="audio/mpeg" />
        </audio>
```

```
<ul id="playlist">
  <?php if($lists) { foreach ($lists as $list) { ?>
    <li class="active">
      <a href="music/<?php  echo $list;  ?>.mp3">
         <?php  echo $list;  ?> </a>
    </li>   
  <?php }}?>
</ul>
```

```
$('#playlist').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var src = $(this).attr('href');
    $('#audio source').attr('src', src);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
$('#audio').load();
```

use the load for load new audio

```
$('#audio').get(0).play();
```

Comment: can u add ur code in jsfiddle maby u have another problem :)

Comment: its free u dont want to create account xD

Comment: some browser didnt play mp3 file u need to add tow source
  <source id="oggSource" type="audio/ogg" />
    <source id="mp3Source" type="audio/mp3" />

try to add tow source and chnage also tow source when change song

Comment: I did but when i add manually a mp3 song in <source> tag it worked but not working when i use click event to change src.

Comment: ok maby u have problem with php u echo song path with php 
now try
$('#playlist li a').on() ..  add listener to all a in #playlist

Comment: Thanks bro for your time but still it not working.. ok

Comment: xD if u have fb account add me on
fb.com/deluxezeus998
i will help u on teamviewr if u want